# Change Class After Notification Is Clicked Android

Tags: java, android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, proximity

I am trying to change my class to to go to Login.java I have tried numerous solutions but can't seem to get it. I have a PromximityAlert set-up to check location and after that location is confirmed it will display the notification and when that notification is clicked, it will initiate the Login class.

Here is my code:

```
public class ProxAlertActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE = 1; // in Meters
    private static final long MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE = 1000; // in Milliseconds

    private static final long POINT_RADIUS = 1000; // in Meters
    private static final long PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION = -1; 

    private static final String POINT_LATITUDE_KEY = "POINT_LATITUDE_KEY";
    private static final String POINT_LONGITUDE_KEY = "POINT_LONGITUDE_KEY";

    private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.example.mysqltest.ProximityAlert";

    private static final NumberFormat nf = new DecimalFormat("##.########");

    private LocationManager locationManager;

    private EditText latitudeEditText;
    private EditText longitudeEditText;
    private Button findCoordinatesButton;
    private Button savePointButton;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 
                        MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATE, 
                        MINIMUM_DISTANCECHANGE_FOR_UPDATE,
                        new MyLocationListener()
        );

        latitudeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.point_latitude);
        longitudeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.point_longitude);
        findCoordinatesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.find_coordinates_button);
        savePointButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_point_button);

        findCoordinatesButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                populateCoordinatesFromLastKnownLocation();
            }
        });

        savePointButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveProximityAlertPoint();
            }
        });

    }

    private void saveProximityAlertPoint() {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location==null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No last known location. Aborting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        saveCoordinatesInPreferences((float)location.getLatitude(), (float)location.getLongitude());
        addProximityAlert(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
    }

    private void addProximityAlert(double latitude, double longitude) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

        locationManager.addProximityAlert(
            41.69519672, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
            -87.80026184, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
            POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
            PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no expiration 
            proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
       );

       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);  
       registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);

    }

    private void populateCoordinatesFromLastKnownLocation() {
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (location!=null) {
            latitudeEditText.setText(nf.format(location.getLatitude()));
            longitudeEditText.setText(nf.format(location.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    private void saveCoordinatesInPreferences(float latitude, float longitude) {
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(getClass().getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
        prefsEditor.putFloat(POINT_LATITUDE_KEY, latitude);
        prefsEditor.putFloat(POINT_LONGITUDE_KEY, longitude);
        prefsEditor.commit();
    }

    private Location retrievelocationFromPreferences() {
        SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(getClass().getSimpleName(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        Location location = new Location("POINT_LOCATION");
        location.setLatitude(prefs.getFloat(POINT_LATITUDE_KEY, 0));
        location.setLongitude(prefs.getFloat(POINT_LONGITUDE_KEY, 0));
        return location;
    }

    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Location pointLocation = retrievelocationFromPreferences();
            float distance = location.distanceTo(pointLocation);
            Toast.makeText(ProxAlertActivity.this, 
                    "Distance from Point:"+distance, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {            
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {           
        }
    }
}

public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

        Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

        if (entering) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
        }
        else {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
        }


        NotificationManager notificationManager = 
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);     

        Notification notification = createNotification();
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Proximity Alert!", "You are near your point of interest.", pendingIntent);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);


    }
    private Notification createNotification() {
        Notification notification = new Notification();

        notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_menu_notifications;
        notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();


        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;

        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

        notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
        notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1500;

        return notification;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this , I think its missing

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

 notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent );
```

Comment: Thank you! That was bothering me so much that I couldn't get it! I really appreciate it!